# how to generate unique session id onload?

Tags: php, ajax, session, session-cookies, sessionid

In the past,I have created a login system where session id was created on click of submit button.So i am familiar about sessions and their usage.But this time around,I am doing some thing different.

*I am tracking users activity and displaying it as a  graph*.The problem is that,the website that I am tracking **does not have a login system**.
There are three pages in website and I need to track all the links and images clicked and based on that I will be creating a string every 30 seconds and inserting it in to db`s table.The same way I will take out some data from table every 30 seconds and send it to js page via ajax.
So,basically I am inserting  and extracting some data every 30 sec and using these data I am plotting my graph.(Thus,graph will be modified every 30 seconds and ultimately giving a tracking history.This is done by ajax).I am asking for mechanism,not the code.

**MyQuestion:**

1. how do i create different different session ids for different users
   (who will not login or register).My goal is to give every user a
   graph based on their own tracking history.I don't want to mix up
   person A's tracking history with person B's.
2. How do I push data from table to js page every 30seconds?

Comment: sessions are, unless high-jacked, user unique.

Comment: i now outsource all my site user metrics to google analytics - yet to find anything better

Comment: $_SESSION['username']=username;---->this is how i set session variable,how to do the same with id's and the main concern is
how do i make every graph user see-his own tracking history?

Comment: log the data with [session_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) then use that to determine who sees what

Comment: onload I need to create a sessionId using session_id()..thats fine.But I want to maintain the same sessionid on 2nd and 3rd page so that graph representation is not interrupted and continued from where it is left of.What I want is unless the tab is closed,the same id should be maintained i.e new graph is to be drawn only when some different user comes on website(or closes the browser )

Comment: session id wont change from page to page

Answer (score 0):

Just because your site doesn't have a login system doesn't mean you still cannot use sessions.

A solution for you may be to use jQuery to listen for all click events, then `push` values onto a value... Then a timer, such as `setInterval`, to call an AJAX function and send up the json-encoded data to the server... from there, parse and log the data.

Comment: yes.I am also thinking the same mechanism.this is what i am trying to find....$_SESSION['username']=username;---->this is how i set session variable when login is present,how to do the same with id's and the main concern is how do i make every graph user see-his own tracking history?

Comment: You can push data onto a session array.. such as `$_SESSION['username']['trails'][] = "something";`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how about sess_id, and i sure, you really don't need it

I reccomend to you this:

detect user IP & User Agent and for each user and save it to db (if user not login & register)

and (or)

make cookies

> How do I push data from table to js page every 30seconds?

Em...

```
setTimeOut(function(){},30000);
```

Or i not fully understand your question

Comment: I dont think its possible without sessionId...
MYquestion-->each user should be able to see his own tracking history on a graph which is updated every 30sec(no login system provided in website)